# Hashmap returns null value when using a nested hashmap as the key

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have defined a hashmap as follows:

```
 private HashMap<HashMap<String,String>,String> like_map=new HashMap<HashMap<String,String>,String>();
```

The following operation returns a null string.

```
HashMap<String,String> fetch_key = new HashMap<String,String>();
fetch_key.put("Username", "Status");
String d=like_map.get(fetch_key);
```

Can anyone explain me why does String d return null?Thanks.

PS: I have put a value in the like_map hashmap as follows

```
HashMap<String,String> acctyp = new HashMap<String,String>();
acctyp.put("Username","Status");
like_map.put(acctyp, "0");
```

Comment: The entry is probably not present. Btw, using a map as a key is odd design. Why don't you create a custom key class for your two string values? Override `equals` and `hashCode` accordingly and you should be fine.

Comment: `HashMap` is mutable. Don't use it as key in another `Map`.

Comment: did you put anything into `like_map`? if not, then of course you get `null` from every query to it.

Comment: yes i have.Please check the edited question

Comment: Works for me with the code you posted and in a Java 8 environment, so I assume you're doing something different - which probably is due to using a map as the key. You'll save yourself some headaches but chosing a different design.

Comment: your code is works for me.

Comment: You'd be better off using `Map<String,String>` and using the `Map.toString()` as your key. You'd get a much more stable and usable solution.

Comment: Or (depending on your use case) a java.util.IdentityHashMap fits? This map implementation lookup for keys with the exact same reference instead of .equals()

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon why not Map.hashCode() ? Depending on map content Map.toString() could be very huge amount of data

Comment: @salyh - Because `Map.hashCode()` could be the same for two different `Map`s. BTW - the `toString` will be approximately the same size as the `Map` contents.